# How to access local storage in background task (for audio) in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I made a Background task for playing audio in my windows phone 8.1 app. But I want to access some local storage files, but there is some problem. I made following attempts

**Attempt 1:**

```
StorageFile contentFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(guid + "_rec_c.txt");
text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(contentFile);
```

**Error:**

App execution stops and it goes to the following code in App.g.i.cs

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
{
    if(global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
};
#endif
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
{
    StorageFile contentFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(guid + "_rec_c.txt");

    text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(contentFile);
});
```

**Error**
 It gives null reference exception in line 1, supposedly 
    CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread() is returning null.

**Attempt 3:**

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
{
    StorageFile contentFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(guid + "_rec_c.txt");

    text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(contentFile);
});
```

**Error:**

It gives `System.InvalidOperationException` and additional information is Additional information: A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)

Please tell how can I access local storage file in background task.

Comment: 2 and 3 won't work because there isn't a UI thread in a background task. What is the exception in 1?

Comment: We need to know what the exception raised in #1 is. When visual studio breaks, hover over the `e` variable to inspect it.

Comment: Please show localFolder declaration.